# Checkin if a Variable File is in another directory

Tags: bash

I'm looking to check if a variable file is in another directory, and if it is, stop the script from running any farther. So far I have this:

```
#! /bin/bash 
for file in /directory/of/variable/file/*.cp;
do
test -f /directory/to/be/checked/$file;
echo $?
done
```

I ran an echo of $file and see that it includes the full path, which would explain why my test doesn't see the file, but I am at a loss for how to move forward so that I can check.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: `${file##*/}` instead of `$file`

Answer (score 1):

I think you want

```
#! /bin/bash 
for file in /directory/of/variable/file/*.cp  ; do
   newFile="${file##*/}"
   if test -f /directory/to/be/checked/"$newFile" ; then
      echo "/directory/to/be/checked/$newFile already exists, updating ..."
   else
      echo "/directory/to/be/checked/$newFile not found, copying ..."
   fi
   cp -i "$file" /directory/to/be/checked/"$newFile"
done
```

Note that you can replace `cp -i` with `mv -i` and **move** the file, leaving no file left behind in `/directory/of/variable/file/`.

The `-i` option means interrogate (I think), meaning if the file is already there, it will ask you `overwrite  /directory/to/be/checked/"$newFile"` (or similar) to which you must reply `y`. This will only happen if the file already exists in the new location.

IHTH

Comment: Nice :) Although, I would consider using `nullglob` and `[[ ]]` instead of `test`. And OP wants to exit the script if the file is found.

Comment: yes, I'd use `[[ -f ... ]]`, but I'm trying to keep the code so the O.P. doesn't have too much new info to take in. Thanks for the feed back and all your good A's lately.

Answer (score 0):

The command `basename` will give you just the file (or directory) without the rest of the path.

```
#! /bin/bash 
for file in /directory/of/variable/file/*.cp;
do
    test -f /directory/to/be/checked/$(basename $file);
    echo $?
done
```